# Run scripts and css of html file fetched with chrome.runtime.getURL()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and would like to add the contents of an html file to the document when the browser action is activated. I can get the html added, but the css (or even included scripts) are not activated although I want them to be.

This is happening in content.js (the activated content_script). When the browser action is pressed, this function is called:

```
function addInitialView() {
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('searchView.html')).then().then((response) => response.text())
    .then((html) => {
        $("body").prepend(html)
    })
}
```

The code of searchView.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The styling is (styles.css)

```
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```

When the button is activated, I expect h1 and p to appear and be styled at the top of the screen. They both do appear, but they are not styled (text is still black and background is still white).

Additionally, while the styling of the css file doesn't seem to be applied, having the link to the css file does center the text whereas not including it has it left-aligned. I cannot find another css file that might be adding any styling.

I have added both `searchView.html` and `styles.css` to `web_accessible_resources` in the manifest.

Any suggestions on how I could get the css applied, and even to have scripts in the html file to be run before adding to the body?

Edit:
Here is some additionally requested information:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "0.4.2",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "active16.png",
    "48": "active48.png",
    "128": "active128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Title"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com https://js.stripe.com/v3/; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "searchView.js",
    "styles.css",
    "searchView.html",
    "payment.html",
    "active48.png"
  ]
}
```

screenshot of directory:
[image]

Comment: have you tried writing them directly in the HTML document rather than calling the style as an instance? `<style>body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
p {
  color: red;
}</style>`

Comment: Or you can fetch those css files explicitly just like you fetch html now (and add DOM style element) or use fully qualified URLs in html like chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/foo.css

Comment: @raku That did work, though I don't think it would make for a very scaleable solution. But that did make me think that there might be an issue with the file/source, so I added a test script that just did a log and at `searchView.js`. This failed though and was not found -- needing to use something like chrome.runtime.findURL. To that end, could you explain how to use a fully qualified url @wOxxOm? I tried your example (replacing foo) but got `chrome-extension://invalid/`

Comment: there are 2 things that could be happening here. Can I see your manifest.json and a screenshot of the folder location of your extension?

Comment: Uhm, that full URL trick works only inside css files, not in html. You can use replace() on `html` parameter to insert this full URL into the html string or use jquery methods after insertion to add style elements that point to css files.

Comment: @EndersJeesh I can guarantee that I can fix this problem if you show me the manifest.json and the directory of your addon folder.

Comment: @raku I have updated the description to include the information you were wanting.

Comment: ok ill check it out..

Comment: @EndersJeesh did the below solve your problem?

Comment: @EndersJeesh can pls vote my answer as the correct one pls..

Comment: @EndersJeesh not cool man I took a lot of effort in answering this yet you don't even mark my answer as correct, you even tried to delete it. you could at least vote as correct.. zzzz

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have inputted the wrong path for your styles.css. Instead, It should have been:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

Since the location of your `searchView.html` is the same as `styles.css`.

I don't use jquery because it keeps us in the ground and dependent but your script here:

```html
function addInitialView() {
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('searchView.html')).then().then((response) => response.text())
    .then((html) => {
        $("body").prepend(html)
    })
}
```

It is prepending inside the body which theoretically still works but the code would have multiple headers and titles tag on a single page. Refine it if you must.

You are running your CSS using your content script, so you may also consider adding CSS in the "content_scripts" section in your manifest.json like this:

```js
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "content.js"],
      "css":["style.css"]
    }
  ]
```

If your goal is to totally replace the entire content of a page. If not then you would have to make your style extremely unique with ids and classes.