# Font Awesome: Stacking icons and getting pixel perfect sizing

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to use the stacking technique built into Font Awesome to display small icons inside of a circle. I'd like however to have total control over the size of the circle - more so then the sizing options they have available.

I've built a proof of concept, which works, but the circle doesn't display at the desired dimensions. I have specified for it to be 60x60, however if you inspect the element the container is the correct size but the actual circle icon is inset a bit.

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Courier;
}

.fa-stack.custom {
  font-size: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: pink;
}

.fa-stack.custom .circle {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.fa-stack.custom .icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="fa-stack custom">
      <i class="circle fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="icon fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/nxo2s1gt/13/

Any ideas for getting this to work for exact pixel dimensions?

Comment: I'm not sure if u would vote right after I answered it. I can actually answer this question but yeah I'm too lazy to do so right after this happen. can you help me out here pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846566/run-scripts-and-css-of-html-file-fetched-with-chrome-runtime-geturl?noredirect=1#comment109415460_61846566

Comment: @raku Sorry I do not understand your comment and the link doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have better accuracy if you consder the V5 and the SVG version. The height is defined as `2em` so using `30px` as `font-size` will give you the needed result.

```css
.fa-stack.custom {
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.fa-stack.custom .icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
<span class="fa-stack custom">
      <i class="circle fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="icon fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
```

A little bigger if you want the circle to be exactly `60px` since the path doesn't cover the whole viewbox area:

```css
.fa-stack.custom {
  font-size: 30.97px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.fa-stack.custom .icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
<span class="fa-stack custom">
      <i class="circle fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="icon fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    
   
 <p>Below the SVG of the circle to notice the small gaps</p>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"style="border:1px solid;"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg>
```

You can use CSS variables to make easier to handle. The value `98.66` comes from the fact that if the SVG is `100px` height the path inside will be `98.66px` height:

```css
.fa-stack.custom {
  font-size: calc(var(--s)*(50/96.88));
  background-color: pink;
}

.fa-stack.custom .icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
<span class="fa-stack custom" style="--s:60px">
      <i class="circle fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="icon fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    
    
    <span class="fa-stack custom" style="--s:70px">
      <i class="circle fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="icon fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    
     <span class="fa-stack custom" style="--s:100px">
      <i class="circle fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="icon fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
```